# Does spring-data-dynamodb library work with AWS SDK v2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Spring app that connects to 4 dynamoDb tables in AWS.

I am looking to use https://github.com/boostchicken/spring-data-dynamodb

In my local setup I was able to get this to work with the Basic credentials being used to instantiate the client.

In our elevated environments, we do not use basic credentials and use CMK keys and use the IAM role through WebIdentity Provider to connect to the DB.

For this we would like to use AWS SDK V2 to connect to the database.

However, it looks like with the SDK V2 dynamoDB enhanced client, we would have to write the CRUD methods using the client APIs and not be able to rely on JPA which the above library allows us to do.

Anyone had any luck with that route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that package has ever been upgraded to use SDK V2 or JDK 17+.

You can try sprint starter for your use case: https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/index.html#spring-cloud-aws-dynamoDb

Comment: thanks. spring cloud aws .. is it compatible with spring 2.7.5 or only for versions 3+